# How to add jar files to a service in procun?

Tags: java, procrun

I am using Java as windows service. I used procrun method. Normally my service is working. I have API and I want use this API in my Java code , when service is working my API should work.

I added .jar files in my Java project then got error like this :

```
Failed to install service
2018-02-12 13:18:15 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Exception in thread "main" ror: reporting/MCLReportingServiceAPI
at MyServicee.start(MyServicee.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: reporting.MCLReportingServiceAPI
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Normally my all file in directory like this :

```
C:\Users\xxx\workspace\MyService\src
MyServicee.Class
MyServicee.Java
Myservicee.exe
MyServiceew.exe
```

I put manually all .jar files in this directory(and also bin) , it again did not work.

In terminal I used this command:

```
MyServicee.exe //IS//MyServicee  --Description="Mytest Service" --Install=%CD%\MyServicee.exe --Jvm=auto --Classpath=%CD% --StartMode=jvm --StartClass=MyServicee --StartMethod=start --StopMode=jvm --StopClass=MyServicee --StopMethod=stop --LogPath=%CD%\logs --StdOutput=auto --StdError=auto --Startup=auto
```

If anyone help me , I will be glad.

Best Regards

Comment: Usually the dependencies are packed into an artifact like .WAR or .jar file

Comment: My questions like this , I have many. jar files but my service did not recognize it. In procrun how I can add .jar files inside?